# Default drop down field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came up with a function to make the default drop down label display USA. My code is invalid. How do I execute this correctly?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    populateCountries("Country__c", "State_Province__c");
    populateDataLayer();
    jQuery("#Country__c").val("USA").change();
});
```

Comment: What exactly is invalid? What doesn't work? What error do you get? What happens in `populateCountries` and `populateDataLayer`? Do they execute correctly? What kind of an element is `#Country__c` (`select` or `option` or something different)?

Comment: Instead of displaying "USA" as the default selection the select drop down displays "select country". All of the countries populate correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `.change()`, [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) applies an event listener to the item, not update it.  You should only need the `.val(...)` in order to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.change()`

Also, confirm that the VALUE of your dropdown contains "USA" and not the text inside the option element.